# AWS S3 URL getting encoded when downloading image file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

Need help with the following issue.

The parameter in Aws S3 image url getting encoded when trying to download via wso2 process.

for example Signature sent in parameter along with image url is
**"RmHyI5zRW5nxwWvitbWMsa%2FEwjA%3D"**

However when trying to send the request from wso2 call mediator its rejected by aws server with following message where certain characters in signature have changed **"RmHyI5zRW5nxwWvitbWMsa/EwjA="**

The characters such as
*%2F changed as '/', %2B as '+' and %3D as '='* and as result getting signature mismatch error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Error>
            <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
            <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
            <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIA4OAOFXPAHYQCKZGD</AWSAccessKeyId>
            <StringToSign>GET

application/json

x-amz-security-token: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
/smile-results-prod/production/000000/353/353-0000010928-hmwgs7m5xvquv196pv48uly3rpobfp/SID_Preview_Full.jpg</StringToSign>
            <SignatureProvided>RmHyI5zRW5nxwWvitbWMsa/EwjA=</SignatureProvided>
            <StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 6a 73 6f 6e 0a 31 36 39 33 38 31 35 30 38 32 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2d 74 6f 6b 65 6e 3a 49 51 6f 4a 62 33 4a 70 5a 32 6c 75 58 32 56 6a 45 47 63 61 43 58 56 7a 4c 58 64 6c 63 33 51 74 4d 69 4a 47 4d 45 51 43 49 45 72 62 46 36 2b 33 51 6a 31 65 3 8 6d 77 67 73 37 6d 35 78 76 71 75 76 31 39 36 70 76 34 38 75 6c 79 33 72 70 6f 62 66 70 2f 53 49 44 5f 50 72 65 76 69 65 77 5f 46 75 6c 6c 2e 6a 70 67</StringToSignBytes>
            <RequestId>SG78VW8C3M74MB6D</RequestId>
            <HostId>EhqRjZNgna9/eDzMryNIiYYbN5mw14oLgmXEhsx28yMvVrBShweObyHxku810k8ecobkai+Twjg=</HostId>
        </Error>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
**your text**
```

```
 <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/test">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="$body//image_url" name="uri.var.selfie_image" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
              <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.selfie_image}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you would have needed **URL safe** Base64 encoding replacing `+/` with `-_`, and dropping the **padding** with `=`s. _I have no idea though_

Comment: Did you try with the WSO2 S3 connector? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/connectors/amazons3-connector/amazons3-connector-example/

Comment: the image URL is basically coming to us from the service provider as a callback response.  With the URL we can download it from browser or postman. It only causes the issue when send it via call mediator. We have not used S3 connector as its just a get that we will do with the given endpoint.